# Accessing the value of the last iteration from inside the loop

Tags: c++, std

I know this might be just an if statement that i don't know where to place but i am having difficulties understanding how to proceed.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float a;
    float sum;
    float tA = 5050 ;
    int b [5] = {5, 10, 15, 30, 100};
    double bin;
    double divident;
    cout<<"Random numbers generated between 0 and 1:"<<endl;
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        a = (float) rand()/RAND_MAX; 
        sum += a;
        cout << a << "\t Total: " << sum << "\t Bin: " << a* divident << endl;
    }
        cout << "Total of Random Numbers: " << sum << endl;
        divident = tA/sum;
        cout <<"Divident: "<< divident << endl;
        cout <<"Last a: "<< a << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Random numbers generated between 0 and 1:
0.228659         Total: 0.228659         Bin: 0
0.337218         Total: 0.565877         Bin: 0
0.955376         Total: 1.52125          Bin: 0
0.356451         Total: 1.8777           Bin: 0
0.7963           Total: 2.674            Bin: 0
Total of Random Numbers: 2.674
Divident: 1888.55
Last a: 0.7963
```

The dividend should be a variable (tA)/the sum of all 5 random generated numbers (2.674) and every random value of 'a' be multiplied by it on every row (inside bin column). But I do not know exactly how to access it since in the code it is the last iteration of 'sum'

as you can see my next step is to place all five values into a designated array bin *int b[5](labeled 5, 10, 15, 30, 100). and eventually multiply the expected frequency in every bin with the bin label(5,10,15.. 1000) I'm thinking std map or something similar, so any advanced std solutions or pointers (sic) on how to proceed further would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Initializing `sum` might help. Did you ever try to use a debugger?

Comment: yes, what i don't understand is how to access the last iteration of the loop before the iteration actually takes place? It's not there yet.

Comment: If the loop condition is `i < 5` the last iteration can be detected by `if (i == 4)` obviously (assuming a steady increase of `i` by one). Was that your question?

Comment: Outputting the product based on an undefined value (`divident`) (even when the other factor is a random value) doesn't make much sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only compute `divident` after the end of the loop, but you want to use it starting with the first iteration: that is not possible using one single loop. You should use two loops, first one to compute `sum` and `divident`, and second one to display the values:

```
float sum = 0;
...
double arr[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    a = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    sum += a;
    arr[i] = a;
}
divident = tA / sum;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    a = arr[i];
    cout << a << "\t Total: " << sum << "\t Bin: " << a * divident << endl;
}
```

Comment: The two loop solution indeed works. If i cout this after the second loop 
`cout << "*arr Sum is: " << sum << "\t arr is: " << *arr <<endl;
 cout << "a Sum is: " << sum << "\t a is: " << a <<endl;` 
*arr gives me the first total (iteration) and a is the last one . what if I want to access, let's say the third one, why isn't something like arr[3] possible?

Comment: @bahrenze1: Why would it not be possible? `arr[3]` is perfectly defined and is the fourth values (index start at 0...)